# Why only half of my video has been rendered?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, file-format, animation-nodes

I have spent over 9 hours waiting for blender to produce my 19 second video  and in the end it deleted half of my video.

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: My start frame is : 1   my end frame is :600   and my step frame is: 1. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Were you trying to render to a video or image sequence?

Comment: Maybe it crashed, maybe some other software tried to open the file while it was still being writtent. There are many possible reasons. Did you tried to render an opengl video sequence just to see if everything is working fine?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to take a wild guess here without more info, but is it possible you forgot to set the correct amount of frames?

By default, Blenders animations are 250 frames long, which is ~10 seconds (depending on framerate) which is about half of your video. Did you change "End Frame" to the correct value here?

[image: End frame for animations]

Comment: My start frame is :1  my end frame is:600 and my step frame is :1. Do I need to change anything?

Comment: No that sounds fine. Can you upload so I can check other settings?

Comment: How do I upload?

Comment: Do you want me to upload a picture of my settings?

Comment: Yes you could, but maybe the entire blend file is easier since some settings might be spread out. You can do it here:
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
(Feel free to remove the objects themselves if you want to )

Comment: After more than 50 hours it finally finished, and this time it worked!